# Remove page refresh browser popup

Tags: javascript, page-refresh, onbeforeunload, window.onunload

I added page beforeunload and unload functions as follows:

```
window.onunload = function (e) 
                {
                    //mycode1
                    return '';
                };
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
                    //mycode2
                    return '';
                }
```

and they are getting called after browser confirmation popup occurs. But now I want to unbind these functions. I tried

```
window.onunload = null;
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

But seems like they are not working and still browser refresh confirmation popup appears.

Comment: How exactly did you add them in the first place?

Comment: Normally, you just remove whatever it was you added, so add some detail on what is going on here because it doesn't make much sense right now

Comment: @CBroe did like this window.onunload = function (e) {
                        //mycode
                        return '';
                    }

Comment: @Huangism, I edited the code. could you check?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the initial code you added? or are you trying to unbind them upon some interaction or condition

Comment: @Huangism, I need myCode1 and myCode2 to be run. but I don't want to show that refresh confirmation popup when I click a submit or any other action which leaves the page. Yes I'm trying to unbind them before form submission

Comment: @ShamithaSilva remove the return statement, however this method isn't very reliable and might not work the same on all browsers